# subtracting integer from a date format VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, date, subtraction

Below is the code i have developed. The objective is to subtract "1" or "2" from the data, depending on if is a saturday or a sunday, respectively. Column 3 contains the dates in short date format, column 5 contains the same dates but converted to "dddd" format.

The error occurs within the for loop at the line

```
if cells(i,5).Value = "Sat" Then
```

The interesting thing here is that the code runs without an "error" per say, it just skips over the if statement complelety, at that line.

```
Sub DataChange()
    Dim i
    Dim n
    n = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 4 to n
        If Cells(i,5).Value = "Sat" Then
            Cells(i,3).Value = Cells(i,3).Value - 1
        End If
        If Cells(i,5).Value = "Sun" Then
            Cells(i,3).Value = Cells(i,3).Value - 2
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the dates are converted, not only displayed in the format "dddd"? If you just changed the format, `cells(i,5).Value`is still a Date, not a String, and can't be compared to "Sat". in this case you should use `Cells(i,5).Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace it all with:

```
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    With Cells(i, 3)
        .Value = .Value - IIf(Weekday(.Value, vbSaturday) < 3, Weekday(.Value, vbSaturday), 0)
    End With
Next
```

---

The `Weekday()` method returns an integer representing a day of the week, based on the start day that you provide. `Weekday(.Value, vbSaturday)` will return `1` for Saturday, and `2` for Sunday. Combined with an immediate If `IIf()` we can check that the value returned is less than 3 (e.g. 1 or 2) and if it is, subtract that from the date in column C

Answer (score 0):

> column 5 contains the same dates but converted to "dddd" format

"dddd" exposes "Saturday" not "Sat" that is exposed with "ddd".

Still try to change Cells(i,5).Value with Cells(i,5).Text:

```
If Cells(i,5).Text = "Sat" Then ....
```

or

```
If Cells(i,5).Text = "Saturday" Then ....
```